# UI gets freeze when parsing large chunks of data even in web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker, sheetjs

I am using Sheet JS to manipulate the contents of an Excel file that is being uploaded to the web app. When parsing a file that has more than 100,000 datasets, I used **Web Worker** to do it, but even though the UI still freezes, I used the **Performance** tab under the DevTools to track the parsing time, and it shows that I am getting frame drops.

Can you help me how to fix this?

consolidateWorkerV2:

```
export const consolidateWorkerV2 = () => {
  const workerCode = `
    /* Load standalone script from CDN */
    import * as XLSX from "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.20.1/package/xlsx.mjs";
    /* This callback will run once the main context sends a message */

async function getFirstRow(sheet, isInventory) {
  return await new Promise((resolve) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

      if(isInventory){
        const sheetRange = "A4:Y5"
        const arr = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet, { range: sheetRange });
        if(arr.length > 0) {
          resolve(arr);
          break;
        };
      } else {
        const sheetRange = "A1:Y" + i.toString();
        const arr = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet, { range: sheetRange });
        if(arr.length > 0) {
          resolve(arr);
          break;
        };
      }
      
    };
  }); 
};

function getWorkbook(startRow, endRow, sheet, range, sheetName, headers){
  const chunkRange = { s: { r: startRow, c: range.s.c }, e: { r: endRow, c: range.e.c } };
  const sheetRange = XLSX.utils.encode_range(chunkRange);
  const SHEET_OPTIONS = { range: sheetRange, skipHeader: false, header: headers }
  const chunk = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet, SHEET_OPTIONS);
  const chunkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(chunk);
  const workbook = { SheetNames: [sheetName], Sheets: { [sheetName]: chunkSheet } };
  return workbook;
};

self.addEventListener('message', async (e) => {
  try {
    const files = e.data.files; // Get the File object from the message
    for (const [index, item] of files.entries()) {
      const isFinished = index === files.length - 1;
      const file = item.file;
      const filename = item.file.name
      const data = await item.file.arrayBuffer();
      const readWorkbook = XLSX.read(data);
      
      for (const sheetName of readWorkbook.SheetNames) {
        const sheet = readWorkbook.Sheets[sheetName];
        const OPTIONS = { blankrows : false, defval: ''};
        const rowLength = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(sheet, OPTIONS);
        const totalRows = rowLength.length + 1;

        const inventoryBookPattern = /inventory[-_ ]?book/i;
        const isInventory = inventoryBookPattern.test(filename);
        const firstRow = await getFirstRow(sheet, isInventory);

        const range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet["!ref"]);
        const headers = Object.keys(firstRow[0]);

        // Split the workbook into chunks and send each chunk separately
        if(totalRows > 1000){
          for (let startRow = range.s.r + 1; startRow <= range.e.r; startRow += 1000) {
            const MAXIMUM_ROW = 999;
            const endRow = Math.min(startRow + MAXIMUM_ROW, range.e.r);
            const workbook = getWorkbook(startRow, endRow, sheet, range, sheetName, headers);
            const isEndLoop = endRow >= range.e.r;
            postMessage({ workbook, filename, isFinished: isEndLoop });
          } 
        } else {
          const ADDITIONAL_ROWS = isInventory ? 4 : 1;
          const startRow = range.s.r + ADDITIONAL_ROWS;
          const MAXIMUM_ROW = totalRows - (isInventory ? 3 : 0);
          const endRow = Math.min(startRow + MAXIMUM_ROW, totalRows);
          const workbook = getWorkbook(startRow, endRow, sheet, range, sheetName, headers);
          postMessage({ workbook, filename, isFinished: true });
        }       
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    /* Pass the error message back */
    postMessage({ error: String(e.message || e).bold() });
  }
}, false);
`;

const blob = new Blob([workerCode], { type: "text/javascript" });
  const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob), { type: "module" });
  return worker;
};
```

consolidateReport:

```
async function consolidateReport(event) {
event.preventDefault();
try {
  if (!checkBoxFile.length || checkBoxFile.length === 1) {
    const errorMsg =
      checkBoxFile.length === 1
        ? "Need two files checked."
        : "No files checked.";

    throw new Error(errorMsg);
  } else if (!selectedDirectory){
    throw new Error("No directory selected.");
  }
  
  const files = checkBoxFile.filter((file) => file.isCheck === true);
  const worker = consolidateWorkerV2();
  
  if (files.find((file) => file.fileName === "Inventory Book")) {
    setDesiredDateTrigger(true);
    await waitForModalClose();
  }
  
  const newWorkbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  const [date, time] = getCurrentDateTime().split(", ");
  let fileName = namingConvention("Consolidated_Final_Report", date);
  const fileHandle = await selectedDirectory.getFileHandle(fileName + ".xlsx", { create: true });
  let filesCompleted = [];
  setIsLoading(true);

  worker.postMessage({ files });
  worker.onmessage = async (event) => {
    const { workbook, filename, isFinished, error } = event.data;
    if (isFinished) filesCompleted.push(filename);
    // if existing workbook has the same sheet name, then merge
    if (workbook) {
      const journalType = getJournalType(filename);
      try {
        if (newWorkbook.SheetNames.includes(journalType)) {
          const duplicateSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
          const newWorksheet = newWorkbook.Sheets[journalType];
          const dupWorksheet = getDataRange(workbook.Sheets[duplicateSheetName]);
          const OPTIONS = { raw: false, defval: "", };
          const parsedDupWorksheet = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(dupWorksheet, OPTIONS);
          const updatedWorksheet = modifyWorksheet(dupWorksheet, parsedDupWorksheet, duplicateSheetName, journalType, reportDate);
          const newData = updatedWorksheet.map((row) => Object.values(row));
          XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(newWorksheet, newData, { origin: -1, skipHeader: true });
        } else {
          // if no existing sheet name, then add new sheet
          for (const sheetName of workbook.SheetNames) {
            const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
            const worksheetData = getDataRange(worksheet);
            const parsedWorksheet = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { raw: false, defval: "", });
            const updatedWorksheet = modifyWorksheet(worksheetData, parsedWorksheet, sheetName, journalType, reportDate);
            const styledSheet = headerStyling(updatedWorksheet);
            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(newWorkbook, styledSheet, journalType);
          }
        }
      
        if (files.length === filesCompleted.length) {
          console.log("Consolidate started.");
          const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(newWorkbook, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "array", });
          const blob = new File([excelBuffer], fileName + ".xlsx");
          const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();
          await writable.write(blob);
          await writable.close();
          worker.terminate();
          console.log("Consolidated report generated.");
          setIsLoading(false);
        } 
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error at consolidate: ", error);
        worker.terminate();
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    } else if (error) {
      console.log("ERROR: ", error);
      worker.terminate();
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
} catch (error) {
  setIsLoading(false);
  console.log("Error at sidebar: ", error);
  let errorMsg = error.message;
  const typeOfError =
    "An operation that depends on state cached in an interface object was made but the state had changed since it was read from disk";

  if (error.message.includes(typeOfError)) {
    errorMsg =
      "Please close the existing file before generating the report.";
  }
  toast.error(errorMsg, {
    toastId: "error-consolidate", // preventing to show multiple toast
    position: "top-center",
    autoClose: 1500,
    hideProgressBar: true,
    closeOnClick: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    draggable: false,
    theme: "light",
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: If the data is large, just copying it around between the contexts will cause hiccups.

Comment: @tevemadar I'm sorry but could you elaborate more?

Comment: Analyze your code to see where the bloat is (use the performance tools of your browser). But, why don't you generate the whole thing in your worker? If you must have the filehandler in the main thread then do everything until and including the Blob generation in your worker and use the main thread only to write from the handle. (You can pass Blob objects across contexts without the underlying data being copied at all).

Comment: @Kaiido makes sense. Now I put all the processes in the worker, but now I am facing the issue that the XLSX library cannot be read. When I am creating a new workbook, it says "ReferenceError: xlsx__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__ is not defined," even though I already import it in the worker. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You probably have a problem with your bundler. I can't really help on that, sorry. I know it's possible to run sheetjs entirely in a Worker, I do everyday, but in a bare js environment.

Comment: I mistakenly thought that it was the issue, but I just found out that after trying to import it inside the worker, I got the error. I reimplement and use the reference from https://javascript.plainenglish.io/web-worker-in-react-9b2efafe309c then try to import all my user-defined functions to use inside the worker. I guess it doesn't work. Is there any way to import a function from a relative path??